# Check Whether or Not An Input is a Fibonacci Number

Tags: smlnj, ml

```
fun isfib(a) =
   findfib(a,1,1)

and
findfib(b,x,y) =
   val z = x + y
   if b <= 1 then true
   else if z > b then false
   else if z = b then true
   else fib(b,y,z)
```

I'm placing an input into the program and recursively trying to find out if this input is a fib number or not.
I can calculate the xth place of fib in a separate program in 2 lines. But this "input, check if equals fib, do fib to infinity or bust" logic is extremely confusing to me. I'm also getting errors such as "replacing AND with ANDALSO" and "inserting ORELSE" on line 7.1 which is B<=1

Comment: if you are trying to use mutual recursion using the `and` keyword, you should first, make sure that `fib(a,1,1)` calls `fib(b,x,y)`. Also, you should name the second function something different as well.

Comment: what do you mean make sure that fib(a,1,1) calls fib(b,x,y) might I ask?

I tried to rename it to findfib(a,1,1) and I use and to define 
and findfib(b,x,y) = ect. It wants to replace AND with ANDALSO as if its logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean that you should use `and` for cases where you need mutual recursion, in this case it doesn't seems like you really do, for example, you could try something like this:

```
fun fib 0 = 1
    | fib 1 = 1
    | fib n = (fib (n-1)) + (fib (n-2));

fun isfib a = 
    let
        fun eval a b = if a = (fib b) then true else if a < (fib b) then false else eval a (b+1)
    in
        eval a (1)
end;
```

Try running `isfib 5` and `isfib 6` for example. No infinity required.

Comment: I learned that I had to use the let, in, end on my val z = x + y. I did not know this was necessary, but it makes sense now. Thank you.
Now my code words, but yours does the job as well.

Comment: Right, anytime you need to define an 'auxiliary' function that hasn't already been declared previously, and you would like to define it within the function you are working on, you need `let` statements. I should have mentioned that as well.

Comment: @Anthony Barranco, No problem, but on a side note: Your approach is probably better in the sense that you create an auxiliary variable that stores the result of the current Fibonacci number in `val z`, instead of computing it twice as in my example.